# How do I parse and scrape the meta tags of a URL with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to pull the `<h1>` and `<title>` tags,
but I am having trouble getting these:

```
<meta name="description" content="I design and develop websites and applications.">
<meta name="keywords" content="web designer,web developer">
```

I have this code:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Watson' 
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts page.css('title')[0].text puts page.css('h1')[0].text
puts page.css('description')
puts META DESCRIPTION
puts META KEYWORDS
```

I looked in the docs and didn't find anything. Would I use regex to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: give the full html.. your need is unclear..

Comment: Just to clarify: Nokogiri doesn't crawl anything. It only does parsing. Your code, in conjunction with gems like OpenURI and Nokogiri, does the crawling.

Comment: Use https://github.com/BorisBresciani/rails_parse_head

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<meta name="description" content="I design and develop websites and applications.">
<meta name="keywords" content="web designer,web developer">
EOT

contents = %w[description keywords].map { |name|
  doc.at("meta[name='#{name}']")['content']
}
contents # => ["I design and develop websites and applications.", "web designer,web developer"]
```

Or:

```
contents = doc.search("meta[name='description'], meta[name='keywords']").map { |n| 
  n['content'] 
}
contents # => ["I design and develop websites and applications.", "web designer,web developer"]
```

Comment: FYI: The only works when you have the meta tags in the document. If you run this code with one of them removed it'll error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Then something changed in one of many revisions since 2013, because the examples are the exact output from Ruby when the answer was created.

Answer (score 10):

That would be:

```
page.at('meta[name="keywords"]')['content']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution: You can use XPath or CSS.

```
puts page.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content').to_s
puts page.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="keywords"]/@content').to_s
```